# ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (1,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (10, 30))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

i'm fairly new to tensorflow and would appreciate answers a lot.
i'm trying to use a transformer model as an embedding layer and feed the data to a custom model.

```
from transformers import TFAutoModel
from tensorflow.keras import layers
def build_model():
    transformer_model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, config=config)
    
    input_ids_in = layers.Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
    input_masks_in = layers.Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,), name='attention_mask', dtype='int32')

    embedding_layer = transformer_model(input_ids_in, attention_mask=input_masks_in)[0]

    X = layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(embedding_layer)
    X = layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(X)
    X = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(X)
    X = layers.Dropout(0.2)(X)
    X = layers.Dense(30, activation='softmax')(X)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids_in, input_masks_in], outputs = X)

    for layer in model.layers[:3]:
        layer.trainable = False

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

    
model = build_model()
model.summary()
r = model.fit(
            train_ds,
            steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
            epochs=EPOCHS,
            verbose=3)
```

I have 30 classes and the labels are not one-hot encoded so im using sparse_categorical_crossentropy as my loss function but i keep getting the following error

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (1,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (10, 30)).
```

how can i solve this?
and why is the (10, 30) shape required? i know 30 is because of the last Dense layer with 30 units but why the 10? is it because of the MAX_LENGTH which is 10?

my model summary:

```
Model: "model_16"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_ids (InputLayer)          [(None, 10)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
attention_mask (InputLayer)     [(None, 10)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_bert_model_21 (TFBertModel)  TFBaseModelOutputWit 162841344   input_ids[0][0]                  
                                                                 attention_mask[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_17 (Bidirectional (None, 10, 100)      327600      tf_bert_model_21[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_15 (Global (None, 100)          0           bidirectional_17[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)                (None, 64)           6464        global_max_pooling1d_15[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_867 (Dropout)           (None, 64)           0           dense_32[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)                (None, 30)           1950        dropout_867[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 163,177,358
Trainable params: 336,014
Non-trainable params: 162,841,344
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 is a number of sequences in one batch. I suspect that it is a number of sequences in your dataset.

Your model acting as a sequence classifier. So you should have one label for every sequence.